# Bootstrap containers usage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggling to understand how to use two different containers(container-fuild and container) together.
Lets say that i want to have full page background but the content should be limited to the 1170px.
What is the best approach to do it? Documentation says that containers are not nestable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set background image for body and use plain container.

Please see here : [http://jsbin.com/veyuq/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/veyuq/1)

```
<body >
  <div class="container">
  content
      </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color:red;
}
.container{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```